# How do I use requestAnimationFrame to call my js prototype?

Tags: javascript

I want to call my methid animate indefinetely using requestAnimationFrame. However , the approach I am using does not seem to work.. Here are my codes ..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script>
function object(){
    this.index = 0;
}

object.prototype.animate = function(){
    alert("vimak");
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame( self.animate);
}
me = new object();
me.animate();

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

it gives me the folowing error..
 Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17

How do I fix this ?

**Edited version**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script>
function object(){
    this.index = 0;
}

object.prototype.animate = function(){

    var that = this;console.log(that);
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame( that.animate);
}
me = new object();
me.animate();

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output is

object
 requestAnimationFrame.html:12
Window
 requestAnimationFrame.html:12
Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17

How do I make this work ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must think (debug) about what mean `self` on that context.

Use a local variable to bind original context:

```
var that = this;
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame( function() { that.animate(); } );
```

Or use the `bind` function:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );
```

Comment: Just want to point out that `.bind()` is very slow, especially in Chrome and you definitely don't want to use it with requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: And the first example (with the anonymous function closure) is just begging for a memory leak. Try calling that code as a result of a webkitRequestAnimationFrame and watch how quickly your memory gets consumed. That 'callback' CREATES an anonymous function every time it gets run. Neither of these solutions will work in loop/animation contexts...